# Cutting into hood beams

Tags: modification, vents, hood

I'm looking into installing some hood vents on my car. This will require me to cut out the holes for the vents in my hood.

I've seen some videos online of people doing this, some of which have cut into the support beams / additional layers on the underside of the hood.

This video is one of the few I've seen that do so, at 7:00 in: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=74CHW7Y5wdU

This picture illustrates the two parts of the hood that would be cut in to; from the top, going in:
[image]
The green areas are the actual hood sheet and the red lines are the support beams.

My car hood has a restricted amount of this "green space" available for cutting through, and I would need to cut into these beams to be able to fit vents in.

***Is it safe to cut into these beams to make room for bonnet vents? If not, are there any alternatives?***

Comment: Everything is designed to get a crash rating, altering any of the structure changes this, to what extent or danger is anyone's guess. Hoods are designed to fold in such a way it does not come into the passenger cabin during a frontal crash.

Comment: There just about no way we can tell you what effect this will have on the safety of the vehicle. From your question, it sounds as though you are looking to take all of the area out (green as well as the support beams) to be replaced by the vent. My suggestion is to you to separate the skin from the supports, leaving the supports in place having your "vent" over the top of the supports, to give the vent itself support. Depending on the venting material, it is going to bow under its own weight and aerodynamics. Having the supports remain will give the vent strength as well s the hood itself

Answer (score 1):

**Is it safe to cut into these beams to make room for bonnet vents? If not, are there any alternatives?**

I would say no. Its not safe to cut into your hoods support beams. The reasons where stated in the comments.

Your best alternative imo is to buy a hood with the design you want already built and tested to meet factory standards.